# Is there a way to pull from a git repo straight into a firebase hosted website

Tags: git, firebase-hosting

I have successfully deployed to a firebase hosted app by using the following commands:

```
firebase init
firebase deploy
```

At this stage I am doing a git pull to pull repo down to a staging server and then running the commands above to deploy the code to the firebase hosted site.

I would like to know if its possible to skip the staging server and just pull the github repo straight into firebase. This would basically save me having a server in the picture. I know I could pull it down locally to my computer and do similar but this is still not ideal as if a few of us are contributing to the git repo either someone is going to have to take responsibility for doing the pull to local and then push to firebase or all developers would need to do the same.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks,
Craig.

Answer (score 3):

Deploying directly from Github is not currently a feature of Firebase hosting.

Since you often have to do transpiling, compiling, bundling, minification an the like on the raw (HTML, JS, ES6, SCSS, CSS) source files, it is also seldom a direct deploy, but more of a build process.

Comment: *[Disclaimer: I work for Firebase.]*
It's an interesting idea though, so I'll be sure to relay it to our engineers.

Comment: Fair enough. We will stage for now which will allow us to other things to the code before deploying (minification, etc). Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: couldn't you use a CI service like Travis or Circle CI?

Comment: According to the newer answer below, this is now supported. If that is correct (as it seems to be) you should update your answer. Kinda surprised, actually, that this hasn't happened yet, given your affiliation. (=